# Maximum cardinality of a subspace of a vector space on a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields

Let $k$ be a field with five elements. Let $V$ be the $k$-vector space of $5\times1$ matrices with entries in $k$. Let $S$ be a subset of $V$ such that $u^t v=0$ for all $u$ and $v$ in $S$. What is the maximum possible cardinality of $S$ ?

The question seems to be asking the maximum number of mutually orthogonal vectors over $k$. How do we compute it? Is it same as the number of orthogonal matrices over $k$? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: @FromManToDragon but actually, $V$ has dimension $5^5-1$ right?

Comment: @FromManToDragon oh! ok.The cardinality of the vector space is $5^5-1$, but the dimension is just $5$, you are right, but the final answer is, I hope, not $5$

Comment: The cardinality of $V$ is $5^5$. The dimension of $V$ is $5$.

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard ok, but what is the cardinality of $S$?

Comment: You asked for a maximum cardinality on $S$, an upper bound.  Clearly $|S|\le|V|$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since any linear combination of vectors that fulfil the condition for the elements of $S$ also fulfils the condition, a maximal $S$ is a subspace of $V$. This subspace is self-orthogonal. That is, if its dimension is $k$, its elements fulfill $k$ linearly independent linear equations imposed by the orthogonality. This can only be the case if $k\le5-k$ and thus $k\le2$. We can exhibit a basis for a subspace of dimension $2$ that fulfils the condition: $(1,2,0,0,0)$, $(0,0,1,2,0)$. Thus the maximal dimension $k$ is $2$, and a maximal $S$ has $5^2=25$ elements.

Comment: Are there any notes or book, where I can study about this topic in detail?

Comment: @user388189: I'm sure there are, but I don't know them, I didn't learn these things from books or notes. You could ask a question here for a book recommendation (there's even a tag for that, [tag:book-recommendation]).

Comment: @joriki you mentioned in your answer that ."this can only be the case if $k<5-k$ and thus $k \leq 2$ .can you please tell me about this condition ,because i am also facing problem while solving this problem. Thankyou

Comment: @TheStudent: You quoted it incorrectly. I concluded $k\le5-k$, not $k\lt5-k$. The maximal subspace $S$ of dimension $k$ is a subspace of $V$, which has dimension $5$. The elements of the subspace fulfill $k$ linearly independent linear equations. Thus, the subspace has at most dimension $5-k$. Thus $k\le5-k$, or $2k\le5$. Since $k$ is an integer, that implies $k\le2$.

Comment: @joriki Can you please say what is the meaning of $k$ linearly independent linear equations and how you got $k \le 5 - k$? Thank you.

Comment: @GA316: Linear equations (to be more precise, in this case: homogeneous linear equations) form a vector space: You can form linear combinations of them, and there is a zero element (where all coefficients are zero). The meaning of "linearly independent" in this vector space is the same as in any other: A set of linear equations is linearly independent if no non-trivial linear combination of them yields the zero equation. I got $k\le 5-k$ by combining the two facts mentioned above that the maximal subspace $S$ has dimension $k$ and that the dimension of $S$ is at most $5-k$.

Comment: @joriki The $k$ independent equations are $a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2+\cdots+ a_{15}x_5 = 0, \dots, a_{51}x_1 + a_{52}x_2+\cdots+ a_{55}x_5 = 0$ where $v_i = (a_{11},\dots,a_{15})$ (for $1 \le i \le k$) is a basis for $S$??. Also, the set of all linear equations with coefficists are from $k$ is what we are considering as vector space where these equations are independent? Given this, still I dont get how $S$ is of dimension atmost $k$. Please explain me. Thank you for efforts.

Comment: @joriki The notation used for the underlying field is also $k$.

Comment: @GA316: I think where you wrote $v_i = (a_{11},\dots,a_{15})$ you meant $v_i = (a_{i1},\dots,a_{i5})$? Then yes. You're right that $k$ was a bad choice of variable name on my part because it also denotes the field. About your question: I didn't conclude that $S$ is of dimension at most $k$; I introduced $k$ to denote the dimension of $S$ and then concluded that it is at most $5-k$.

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the clarification. How are we concluding that the dimension of $S$ is at most $5-k$ using the homogeneous equations? Thanks again.

Comment: @joriki how maximal of $S$ can be subspace? If $u,v$ orthogonal ,then as,$u+v$ in maximal of $S$ (which is subspace), then $u$ and $u+v$ are not orthogonal to each other.

Comment: @joriki also one thing I didn't understand with this question that if for all $u,v$ in $S$ , $u,v$ orthogonal,, then if we take $v=u$ ,, then norm of $u$ is $0$ implies only null vector present in $S$, cause norm of non trivial vector can't be $0$. Where did I misunderstand?